# finding $dim\{T\in hom(V,W)|Im(T)\subseteq Z\}$ $Z\subseteq W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I'm having trouble solving the following:

Suppose $V,W$ are vector spaces of a finite dimension over $\Bbb F$ and $Z$ is a subspace of $W$

Say  $A = \{T\in hom(V,W)|Im(T)\subseteq Z\}$

Iv'e managed to prove $A$ is in fact a subspace of $hom(V,W)$ but cannot figure out how to calculate its dimension using the dimensions of $V,W,Z$.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Show that $ \dim A= \dim hom(V,Z)$

Comment: Thanks! I was just about to edit my question and ask exactly that. Just to make sure I understand - Not only are the dimensions the same but in fact $A=hom(V,Z)$?